# Ways to build groups OTHER than direct and semidirect product.

Tags: group-theory

What are the ways to build groups other than the direct product and the semidirect product? Could not find anywhere  and in the Sarracino's book and in a "Socratica" youtube video it's said that there are many ways to build groups. I ask for links to sites where those ways are displayed and for online (pdf) books.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphism_group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HNN_extension https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product ...

Comment: How about the free product?

Comment: For more precision, you should be explicit about what you mean by "build groups".

Comment: Use `@Somos` to ping Somos, @csounder5. Also, the word is "laypeople".

Comment: @Somos: i'm a layman in math and i have no idea how to be more explicit/precise/clear in this matter. It's main that laypeople like me understand the question, so the question should not be changed upto the point that laypeople do not understand it. I got two excelent answers to the question as i formulated it.